# C#How to automatically refresh data from textfile when Usercontrol becomes active?

Tags: c#, listbox, text-files, refresh

I a have form with buttons and usercontrols loading for each button.

1.In one of the usercontrols there is a Listbox that loads items from a textfile.
Here you can also add new items, which updates the listbox and the textfile.

2. The other usercontrol has a Checklistbox that also loads items from the textfile. Here you can remove items from the checklistbox and lines(items) from the textfile, which updates both checklistbox and textfile.

Problem: When going from UserControl to UserControl, it doesn't refresh/update the listbox or checkedlistbox from the textfile after any changes.

Expectation: Everytime the form or any usercontrol is active, it should Update/refresh its data from the textfile automatically.

This loads the textfile in first UC(1) to Listbox.

```
    private void ucAddNewPerson_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.IO.StreamReader ReadFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\Projects\APPAR\Budget app\PersonList.txt");

        string line;
        while ((line = ReadFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            PersonListBox.Items.Add(line);
        }

        ReadFile.Close();

        if (ReadFile == null)
        {
            PersonListBox.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it automtically load changes or do I have to add a refresh button to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use a datasource they could all share the same DS.  Updating it updates the display for them all  ("refresh")

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the FileSystemWatcher class. It will generate events when a file changes, at which point you can reload your control.
The code looks something like this:

```
      public void watchFile()
      {
         var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\Projects\APPAR\Budget app\", "PersonList.txt")
         {
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
         };
         watcher.Changed += (sender, args) => RefreshControl(this);
      }
```

Comment: Notifyfilters does not exist in the current context.
RefreshControl does not exist in the current context.

Is there a reason for this happening?

Sorry if Im asking stupid questions here now, I'm new to coding.

Comment: RefreshControl is something you need to write yourself. NotifyFilter is a property of a FileSystemWatcher object (I'm assuming you've included System.IO). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.notifyfilters?view=netframework-4.7.2 for another example